# Re-use compiled opencv libraries for armv

Tags: opencv, compilation, cmake, package, libraries

Well, for me was very difficult to compile the opencv last version library for the beaglebone black. It took a long time for compiling, and I want to use in any moment without compile again. What I need to do for avoid the compiling using the compiled library that I have?

Answer (score 0):

Once you have built the OpenCV `lib` files, you just need to link with them in your own project. There is no need to rebuild them every time.